# jQuery.parseJSON not parsing using jquery-1.7.1 version

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery-1.7.1 version, my ajax call is as below,

```
var url = "getrequest.do?method=getTemplates";
$.ajax({
         url : url,
         type : "GET",
         dataType : 'text', 
         success:function(response){
                 var templates = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
          }
       });
```

My Response for this ajax call is :

```
{"response":{"result":{"templates":true},"uri":"/api/private/json/templates"}}
```

The parseJSON method throws an parsing error, when i use jquery-1.7.1, but it works fine with jquery.1.5.1.

Can some one help me to debug this issue.

Thanks in advance
Ram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply you can change `dataType` like:

```
dataType : 'json'
```

and you don't need to `$.parseJSON()`, **jQuery** will do it for you.

**CODE**

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
        var templates = response;
        console.log(templates);
    }
});
```